# JAXB 2 - mapping OR relationship between an ELEMENT and a combination of several unwrapped ELEMENTs

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, dtd

I have a DTD defining  an element as such:

```xml
<!ELEMENT slir             ((msids | (msid, codeword?, gsm_net_param, trans_id?)+), 
                           eqop?, geo_info?, loc_type?, prio?, pushaddr?, 
                           service_coverage? %extension.param;)>
```

As I understand it, it means that:

- element `slir` can contain only one `msids`

or,

- element `slir` can contain the whole of `msid, codeword?, gsm_net_param, trans_id?` combination and at least once

They cannot appear at the same time.

So a valid xml should be like:

```xml
<slir>
    <msids>
        ...
    </msids>
</slir>
```

Or,

```xml
<slir>
    <!-- set 1 -->
    <msid>
    <codeword>
    <gsm_net_param>
    <trans_id>
    <!-- set 2 -->
    <msid>
    <gsm_net_param>
</slir>
```

So, if we want to map it in an entity Java class, how should this be?

Ideally I want to wrap the combination into a wrapper class, which is better. Let's call it `MsidGsmData` **but** when marshalling it cannot have the field name print out, but only child element names. Same goes for unmarshalling.

I now have

```java
class Slir {
    @XmlElement
    private Msids msids;

    @XmlElement
    private Msid msid;

    ...

}
```

But I don't know how to map the OR relationship; i.e., `Msid` and the other 4 elements cannot appear at the same time.

(BTW I think it's silly that the combination is not defined as another element, but appear as a whole and stands on the same level as `msids`)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to generate your JAXB classes from the DTD using XJC. It may provide you with some ideas for your design. For example, here's your example with simple *value* declarations of your elements:

**Slir.dtd**

```
<!-- Document Type Definition: Slir                                -->
<!-- Slir.dtd - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573014/ -->

<!ELEMENT   msids (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   msid (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   codeword (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   gsm_net_param (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   trans_id (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   eqop (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   geo_info (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   loc_type (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   prio (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   pushaddr (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT   service_coverage (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT slir  ((msids | (msid, codeword?, gsm_net_param, trans_id?)+),
                eqop?, geo_info?, loc_type?, prio?, pushaddr?,
                service_coverage?)>
```

I modified this [zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-ex001-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) to generate the JAXB classes from your DTD.

> Note: JAXB uses `List<Object>` to represent a *choice* of heterogeneous elements.

**Slir.java**

```
package generated;

import java.util.*;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "msidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId",
    "eqop",
    "geoInfo",
    "locType",
    "prio",
    "pushaddr",
    "serviceCoverage"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "slir")
public class Slir
{
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "msids", required = true, type = Msids.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "msid", required = true, type = Msid.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "codeword", required = true, type = Codeword.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "gsm_net_param", required = true, type = GsmNetParam.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "trans_id", required = true, type = TransId.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> msidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId;
    public List<Object> getMsidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId()
    {
        if (msidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId == null)
            msidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId = new ArrayList<>();
        return this.msidsOrMsidOrCodewordOrGsmNetParamOrTransId;
    }

    protected String eqop;
    public String getEqop() { return eqop; }
    public void setEqop(String value) { this.eqop = value; }

    @XmlElement(name = "geo_info")
    protected String geoInfo;
    public String getGeoInfo() { return geoInfo; }
    public void setGeoInfo(String value) { this.geoInfo = value; }

    @XmlElement(name = "loc_type")
    protected String locType;
    public String getLocType() { return locType; }
    public void setLocType(String value) { this.locType = value; }

    protected String prio;
    public String getPrio() { return prio; }
    public void setPrio(String value) { this.prio = value; }

    protected String pushaddr;
    public String getPushaddr() { return pushaddr; }
    public void setPushaddr(String value) { this.pushaddr = value; }

    @XmlElement(name = "service_coverage")
    protected String serviceCoverage;
    public String getServiceCoverage() { return serviceCoverage; }
    public void setServiceCoverage(String value) { this.serviceCoverage = value; }
}
```

**Codeword.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "codeword")
public class Codeword
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**GsmNetParam.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "gsm_net_param")
public class GsmNetParam
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**Msid.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "msid")
public class Msid
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**Msids.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "msids")
public class Msids
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**TransId.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "trans_id")
public class TransId
{
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**ObjectFactory.java**

```
package generated;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory
{
    public ObjectFactory() { }
    public Msid createMsid() { return new Msid(); }
    public Codeword createCodeword() { return new Codeword(); }
    public GsmNetParam createGsmNetParam() { return new GsmNetParam(); }
    public Msids createMsids() { return new Msids(); }
    public Slir createSlir() { return new Slir(); }
    public TransId createTransId() { return new TransId(); }
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the [HiSrc HigherJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) project.

Comment: My case is that the DTDs other than slir itself cannot be found anywhere. And they are from a standard and are elements themselves, so I cannot invent them arbitrarily. And from what you posted, I understand that OR relationship cannot be validated easily in Java.

Comment: But thanks anyway! Appreciated.